# httpx AsyncClient with a passed Fastapi app works with arbitrary `base_url`s

Tags: python, fastapi, httpx

Here is an example from FastApi's documentation in [Testing section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/async-tests/#example):

> The file main.py would have:
>
> ```py
> from fastapi import FastAPI
>
> app = FastAPI()
>
>
> @app.get("/") async def root():
>     return {"message": "Tomato"}
> ```
>
> The file test_main.py would have the tests for main.py, it could look like this now:
>
> ```py
> import pytest from httpx import AsyncClient
>
> from .main import app
>
>
> @pytest.mark.anyio async def test_root():
>     async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://test") as ac:
>         response = await ac.get("/")
>     assert response.status_code == 200
>     assert response.json() == {"message": "Tomato"}
> ```

`base_url` is supposed to be a prefix which is prepended to the requests created by the client. But I don't see any use-case for it here in this example. So my question is why should we include this `"http://test"` here? What is its purpose?

In fact it can be just `base_url="http://"` or anything:

```py
@pytest.mark.anyio async def test_root():
    async with AsyncClient(app=app, base_url="http://www.facebook.com") as ac:
        response = await ac.get("/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json() == {"message": "Tomato"}
```

If I'm not wrong, it is just there to avoid parsing errors for schema and domain.

Comment: I'm guessing you'd include it if you have endpoints that expect requests to come in on a given http host, for example to look up `user.example.com` endpoints?